# jquery - how to add two variables from .html()

Tags: jquery, mysql, nan

I'm new to this and struggling to understand. How can I add two variables with .html(). All i got is Nan (not a number) or [object Object]. I've already tried parseInt and +.

```
$("select#description").change(function()
{
    $("select#page").html("<option>wait...</option>");
    var id2 = $("select#description option:selected").attr('value');
    $.post("./includes/select_insidepage.php", {id2:id2}, 
    function(data){
    $("select#page").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("select#page").html(data);

            //show price---------------------------
            $("#price").html(data);

           //start----------------------orientation
            $("select#page").change(function()
            {
            $("select#orientation").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            var id3 = $("select#page option:selected").attr('value');
            $.post("./includes/select_orient.php", {id3:id3},
            function(data1){
            $("select#orientation").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#orientation").html(data1);

        //show insidepagePrice----------
        $("label#insidepage").html(data1);

        //computation------------------                     
        var pagePrice = $("#insidepage2").html(data1);
        var prodPrice = $("#price2").html(data);                
        $("#totalprice").html(+pagePrice + +prodPrice);
```

html that will display from jquery

```
<tbody>
                <tr class="top row">
                    <td align="left"> <select id="description"></select>
                </td>
                    <td align="center"> <label id="price"> </label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="side">
                    <td align="left"><select id="page"></select>
                </td>
                    <td align="center"> <label id="insidepage"> </label></td>
                </tr>

                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;  </td>
                    <td class="leftfoot" align="left"> <b> subtotal </b></td>
                    <td class="rightfoot" align="center"><label id="totalprice"> </label> </td>
```

query that will display on drop down list

```
public function ShowType()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM description WHERE id_cat = $_POST[id]";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $type = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';         
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $type .= '<option value="' . $row['id_type'] . '">' . $row['descrip'] . '</option>';
            }
            return $type;
        }

                    public function productPrice()
                    {
                        $sql = "SELECT prodPrice FROM description WHERE id_type = $_POST[id2]";
                        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
                        $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
                        $price = '<label>' . $row['prodPrice']  . '</label>';
                        return $price;
                    }

        public function ShowPage()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM insidepage WHERE id_p = $_POST[id2]";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $page = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $page .= '<option value="' . $row['id_price'] . '">' . $row['insidepage'] . '</option>';
            }
            return $page;
        }

                    public function insidepagePrice()
                    {
                        $sql = "SELECT pagePrice FROM insidepage WHERE id_price = $_POST[id3]";
                        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
                        $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
                        $inside = '<label>' . $row['pagePrice'] . '</label>';
                        return $inside;
                    }
```

Comment: what is `data` and `data1`? `$("#insidepage2").html(data1)` returns a jquery object that is why you are getting the o/p

Comment: Try ` $("#totalprice").html(+data1 + +data)`

Comment: @ArunPJohny nasty .......:-)

Comment: `var pagePrice = $("#insidepage2").html(data1);` this returns a JQuery Object in 'pagePrice'. `.html(Object1 + Object2);` I'm sure this is not what you want to do ^^. What is the type of your data ? Only strings ?

Comment: @Arun P Johnydata and data1 are numbers only.  $("#totalprice").html(+data1 + +data) also returns NaN

Comment: @CelsoTengonciang then `$("#totalprice").html(+data1 + +data)` should work

Comment: @ArunPJohny it also returns NaN. I tried to remove the + sign it only connect the two.

Comment: can you add `console.log(data); console.log(data1)` before adding them and check the console

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks for helping. this is from console <option value="0">choose...</option><option value="1">24 Page</option><option value="2">28 Page</option><option value="3">32 Page</option><option value="4">40 Page</option><label>595</label> process.js:42
<option value="0">choose...</option><option value="1">Landscape</option><option value="1">Portrait</option><label>94</label>

Comment: that means `data` and `data` is not numbers, so you cann't add them

Comment: i tried to convert them in to numbers using parseInt or + but it returns NaN. Is there other way to convert them into numbers? Thanks a lot @ArunPJohny

Comment: try this `function(data) {  $.each(data, function(key, value) { alert(value); });}`

Comment: For better answer poat ur full **jQuery** and **HTML** coding.

Comment: @LakshmanaKumar Thanks for helping. I got <option value="0">choose...</option> in alert per character.

Comment: @LakshmanaKumar I added the related code only. Please let me know if this is okay. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Celso Tengonciang I have updated my answer.

Comment: @LakshmanaKumar thanks! can you explain further? why use    $("#page").empty(); and how $.each(data, function(key, val)) work? It seems to have a same result. I need to populate the drop down list and when a client pick it will show the price.

Comment: @Celso Tengonciang `$("#page").empty();` its to empty listbox. and `$.each(data, function(key, val))` is to get value from `data`

Comment: @LakshmanaKumar Thanks, i got 0 as value. I tried the console.log and I got this <option value="0">choose...</option><option value="1">24 Page</option><option value="2">28 Page</option><option value="3">32 Page</option><option value="4">40 Page</option><label>595</label> all i want is that 595 of <label> is it possible? thanks very big

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. I removed ur few lines to show (eg.) how to add **data**.
U have to use  **$.each(data, function(key, value) {  a = value; });** to convert [object Object] to values.

Im not sure it wont solve ur full problem bcz i dont know what u wil get in `value`

**UPDATED**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    GetValue();
});

function GetValue() {

    $("#description").change(function() {
        $("#page").empty();
        $("#page").html("<option>wait...</option>");
        $.post("./includes/select_insidepage.php",
        {
            id2: $("#description option:selected").text()
        },
        function(data) {
            $("#page").empty();
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                alert('alert 1 : ' + value);
                $('#page').append('<option>' + value + '</option>');
            });
            $("#price").html($('#page option:selected').text());
            var Page = $('#page option:selected').text().split(' Page')[0];
            var Orientation = $('#orientation option:selected').text();

            $("#totalprice").html(parseFloat(Page) + parseFloat(Orientation));
        }, 'json');
    });

    $("#page").change(function() {
        $("#orientation").empty();
        $("#orientation").html("<option>wait...</option>");
        $.post("./includes/select_orient.php",
        {
            id3: $("#page option:selected").text()
        },
        function(data) {
            $("#orientation").empty();
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                alert('alert 2 : ' + value);
                $('#orientation').append('<option>' + value + '</option>');
            });
            $("#insidepage").html($('#orientation option:selected').text());

            var Page = $('#page option:selected').text().split(' Page')[0];
            var Orientation = $('#orientation option:selected').text();

            $("#totalprice").html(parseFloat(Page) + parseFloat(Orientation));
        }, 'json');
    });

}
```

Comment: @Celso Tengonciang copy my code and say what u got in _alert 1_ and _alert 2_. I dont know what the `data` contain. so without knowing it properly i cant help u.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thank you. I got this as result from alert1, in single line < br/> <b> Warning</ b>:2 mysql_fetch_a2ray() expects 
p process.js:30
a process.js:30
r process.js:30
a process.js:30
m process.js:30
e process.js:30
t process.js:30
e process.js:30
r process.js:30
  process.js:30

Comment: @Celso Tengonciang  I dont know what kind of error its. In both alerts u should get ur listbox items one by one.

Comment: Yes, i got that before using your $.each(data, function(key, value). But my goal is to get the price as number when they select from drop down. Thanks

Comment: actually i don't know php. Try something different. In stackoverflow i can suggest or help u. i cant do ur full coding.